# error while installing pycaret in the my venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit, pycaret

I am trying to install pycaret library but gives me an error.

I have tried to update pip but nothing changed

```
          File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vyg39mmt\numpy_8355b93d670144e28fe1a995214ef875\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 90, in <lambda>
        m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TypeError: CCompiler_spawn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: metadata-generation-failed

  Encountered error while generating package metadata.

  See above for output.

  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for details.
  [end of output]
```

I am working with streamlit here, i tried to import pycaret for my model. i ve got an error no modeule 'pycaret', and when i install it, this error happen

Comment: it looks like a problem with pycaret

Answer (score 0):

It can be an **incompatibility** issue between the **numpy** version and the **python** version.

Here is the related SO question: [Type error CCompiler env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535836/typeerror-ccompiler-spawn-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-env) by [Anna Naden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14442297/anna-naden)